# Regex to extract React components with any number of props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I'm working with MDX and I'm trying to use Regex to extract information about the React components within the Markdown.

My regex would need to:

- Recognise any React component

  - this includes the first line of a component with children `<Component>` as well as self closing components `<Component />`
- Capture any number of props passed to the component

  - `prop1="one" prop2={2}`
- Separate each prop into its own array (?)

  - I don't actually know if this is possible

The regex I currently have is:

```
<([A-Z1-6]+)\W(.*)>
```

That regex matches both of these, which is great:

```
<Component />

<Component test="something" something=here">
```

`test="something" something=here"` are being captured into a separate group. But would it be possible to separate each prop into its own group?

It also matches:

```
<Component prop="1" />
```

But captures `/` with the rest of the props. How do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

To not capture the ending / you could change your regex to:

```
<([A-Z1-6]+)\W(.*?)/?>
```

This will make the ending / get caught outside the capture group.

I don't think it's possible to get an arbitrary number of capture groups, one for each property. You would probably need to make a second regex and use that on the result of the capture group with the property values. Something like:

```
(\w+)="([^"]*)"
```

Comment: Thank you! They both work. Any idea how I can change the second Regex to also match props that look like `prop={100}`?

Comment: I think this might actually work `(\w+)=["{]?([^"}]*)["}]?`